# Using the @EnableWebMVC annotation causes exception

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm trying to run a web application using spring boot.

```
Dependencies: compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
compile('org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:8.0.47')
```

There are few .jsp files, like: Login.jsp, Welcome.jsp

Mapping password as hard-coded values.

**My Question is:** When the application runs and the `@EnableWebMVC` annotation is used over the main class, the following exception happens as soon as it hits the URL `http://localhost:8080/login`:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name
>   'Login' in servlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1305)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1069)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1008)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]

But the application runs fine when the annotation `@EnableWebMVC` is removed.

What is happening?

Comment: I recomend you to check this link out for MVC with spring before diving into it.
https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/

Answer (score 0):

`@EnableWebMvc` disables MVC autoconfiguration and allows you to provide exactly what you want. In this case, that means that it switches off the default resource.

You can either use other means to customize your configuration, such as a `*Configurer`, or you can specify exactly what you want with `@EnableWebMvc`. See Boot's `WebMvcAutoConfiguration` to find out what the defaults are, and what you need.